# Minecraft Multiplayer (Java Edition) isn't working for me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have a macOS 10.14.6, and I've been trying to get multiplayer. I've done all of the things Mojang tells you to do- I've turned on LAN and I've made sure that I have the same connection as the other person. I turn on LAN, they click multiplayer, it doesn't show up. They have a macOS as well. Neither of us have firewalls up.

Answer (score -1):

It could possibly be your router blocking the connection between the two devices, so the lan connection never gets further than the router.